# How can I improve the readability of these linq statements?

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I have a hierarchical data tree containing objects of a class called `DataNode`.

Each `DataNode` contains a collection of `Attribute` objects.  Each `Attribute` is essentially a key/value pair, with some helper methods attached.  For example, there is a helper method called `EqualsCodeIndex(x)` that matches a small collection `x` of `int` values to `this` `attribute` and returns `true` or `false`.  All keys and values are strings, because the whole thing is based on a key/value store contained in a text file.

To simplify access to a particular `DataNode`, there is a dictionary in the `DataTree` class that maps all of the nodes in the tree to a unique code:

```
Dictionary<string, DataNode> Codes;
```

The resulting Linq statement to get to a specific `Attribute` value looks like this:

```
string AttributeValue = dataTree
    .Codes[@"R-1\CHE"]
    .Attributes
    .Single(x => x.EqualsCodeIndex(parentAttribute.CodeIndex))
    .Value.Trim();
```

This is not too bad if I only have to retrieve one or two attributes by code and code index, but it's *not so good if I have to retrieve ten or more.*

To attempt to simplify the statement, and allow for the possibility of `EqualsCodeIndex` returning `false` for all attributes in the collection, I added an extension method:

```
public static string AttributeValueMatching
    (this KeyValuePair<string, DataNode> pair, List<int> codeIndex)
{
    var attribute = pair.Value.Attributes
        .Single(x => x.EqualsCodeIndex(codeIndex))

    return attribute == null ? string.Empty : value;
}
```

This simplifies the original linq statement down to:

```
string attributeValue
    = dataTree.Codes[@"R-1\CHE"].AttributeValueMatching(codeIndex);
```

...which is better, but I have a feeling I'm missing something.

---

Are there problems with this approach?  Is there a better, cleaner approach I haven't thought of, maybe making better use of indexers, or perhaps a fluent interface?

Comment: Isn't following `.SingleOrDefault` with `.Value` asking for an NRE?

Comment: @Kirk: An even better reason to encapsulate via the extension method. I've fixed the problem in the sample code, although the final result won't look quite like this.

Comment: What do you mean retrieve twenty or thirty? Create twenty new different variables?

Comment: @svick: Correct. Realistically, it's more like ten; I will need *all* of them (the data-driven algorithm that uses the extracted values is fairly complex). I edited to clarify.

Comment: @Robert, you edited while I was composing my answer(below) you start with a question re: "readability" (for which I think the extension method is a good answer..) and the seem to digress to a question of "which is better" as (perhaps) a performance question. ... or am I missing something?

Comment: @Cos: I'm not concerned about performance...Not yet, anyway.  I'm mostly looking for clever ways to shorten and simplify the retrieval code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that making it into one method with two parameters would look slightly better:

```
Codes.AttributeValueMatching(@"R-1\CHE", codeIndex)
```

Or you could create a wrapper with an indexer:

```
CodesWrapper[@"R-1\CHE", codeIndex]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer to your whole question, but to the "problems with this approach" section I have a suggestion.

Be careful chaining statements after a `SingleOrDefault()` as it could potentially return `null`. If you are absolutely sure it will always have a single value, maybe just call `Single()` and deal with that missed expectation should it ever happen instead of a more generic `NullReferenceException`.

*EDIT*
While writing the above post you made the same changes. Carry on...

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered building an **[Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)** of DataTree?

like

```
public static class DataTreeExtensions
   {
      public static string FetchByAttribute(this DataTree d, string Attribute)
      {
         string AttributeValue = d
                         .Codes[Attribute]
                         .Attributes
                         .Single(x => x.EqualsCodeIndex(parentAttribute.CodeIndex))
                         .Value.Trim();

            return AttributeValue

      }
   }
```

This will allow you to reuse "FetchByAttribute" at will as:

```
string myValue = myTree.FetchByAttribute(@"R-1\CHE");
```

*Edited: changed from DataNode to DataTree...*

Comment: This doesn't quite work, since `DataNode` doesn't own the `Codes` dictionary; `DataTree` does.  But it *could,* with some modification, be an ordinary method on the `DataTree` object.

Comment: I was looking and I had taken dataTree as an instance of DataNode. I have edited my response, and think this will do what you want.

Comment: It's close, although I don't think it needs to be an extension method, since I have to reference the tree in any case. I already suggested an extension method solution in my original question, so I think what you and @svick are saying is, just move the technique higher up in my object hierarchy.

Comment: @Robert, correct. The idea is to encapsulate it into it's own function call, whether that is organic to the object or bolted on as an extension is of little matter... Unless, your need for that function is limited in scope (say you may need to do a lot of it, but only on one page/forms/context... in which case you may isolate the function by namespace and only reference it when needed. Since you control the DataTree object there really is no reason to not make it a static method of the object, or even an instance method.